# How to implement order of operations for an expression in an array?

Tags: ruby

Given the expression

```
1 * 2 / 3 + 4
```

I'm trying to write out all possible variants of the equation when implementing order of operations. Such as:

```
(1 * 2) / 3) + 4
```

and

```
(1 * (2 / 3)) + 4
```

This is what I have now:

```
expression = [1.0, "+", 2.0, "+", 3.0, "+", 4.0]
storage = []

exp1 = expression    #Make new object because insert method will overwrite expression object
storage << exp1.insert(0, "((").insert(4, ")").insert(7, ")")
```

But `exp1`'s changes reflect in expression as well. I even made them in separate methods but the changes keep reflecting on expression.

How do I keep the expression object unchanged? I need to configure the original expression 5 times in total, but I'm struggling to keep it clean when I use `insert`. Reading the Ruby docs, the `insert` method is the only one suitable to what I'm doing.

Do I have to use a different data structure to store `1 * 2 / 3 + 4` other than an array?

Comment: Copy it? That aside, are you sure you're doing what the assignment is supposed to be teaching? Just wedging in parens seems kind of hokey.

Comment: Not an assignment. This is my personal project. If you have a superior method to create all variations of an operation, please assist.

Comment: If you're working on a parser anyway, just modify the parsing rules to produce all the outputs. Otherwise I'm not even sure what the point of the exercise is.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Did it occur to you that others may still be working on answers? Quick selections can also discourage other, possibly better answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours. The point is, there's no rush.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I saw a something that works and I took it.

Comment: @KaMok -- Kinda like how I chose my wife. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `#dup` so that you don't alter the original set:

```
expression.dup.insert(0, "((").insert(4, ")").insert(7, ")")
```

Comment: Way to untangle that question.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def all_equations(expression)
  nums = expression.select { |o| o.kind_of? Numeric }.map(&:to_s)
  ops  = expression.select { |o| o.is_a? String }.uniq
  ops.permutation(ops.size).to_a.map { |ao|
    ([nums.first] + ao.zip(nums[1..-1]).map(&:join)).join }
end
```

**Examples**

```
all_equations [1.0, "*", 2.0, "/", 3.0, "+", 4.0]
  #=> ["1.0*2.0/3.0+4.0", "1.0*2.0+3.0/4.0", "1.0/2.0*3.0+4.0",
  #    "1.0/2.0+3.0*4.0", "1.0+2.0*3.0/4.0", "1.0+2.0/3.0*4.0"]

a = all_equations [1.0, "*", 2.0, "/", 3.0, "+", 4.0, "-", 4.0, "**", 5.0]
  #=> ["1.0*2.0/3.0+4.0-4.0**5.0", "1.0*2.0/3.0+4.0**4.0-5.0",
  #    ...
  #    "1.0*2.0+3.0**4.0/4.0-5.0", "1.0*2.0+3.0**4.0-4.0/5.0",
  #    ...
  #    "1.0**2.0-3.0+4.0*4.0/5.0", "1.0**2.0-3.0+4.0/4.0*5.0"] 
a.size
  #=> 120
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
expression = [1.0, "*", 2.0, "/", 3.0, "*", 3.0] # note `"*"` appears twice
nums = expression.select { |o| o.kind_of? Numeric }.map(&:to_s)
  #=> ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "3.0"] 
ops = expression.select { |o| o.is_a? String }
  #=> ["*", "/", "*"]
a = ops.uniq
  #=> ["*", "/"] 
b = a.permutation(a.size)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["*", "/"]:permutation(2)> 
c = b.to_a
  #=> [["*", "/"], ["/", "*"]] 
c.map { |ao| ([nums.first] + ao.zip(nums[1..-1]).map(&:join)).join }
  #=> ["1.0*2.0/3.0", "1.0/2.0*3.0"]
```

`uniq` has effect only when `ops` contains duplicates.

**Extension**

The following permits the numbers to be reordered as well. (I initially thought this was a requirement, which is the only reason I am offering this modification.)

```
expression = [1.0, "*", 2.0, "/", 3.0, "+", 4.0]
nums = expression.select { |o| o.kind_of? Numeric }.map(&:to_s)
  #=> ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0"] 
ops  = expression.select { |o| o.is_a? String }
  #=> [["*", "/", "+"], ["*", "+", "/"], ["/", "*", "+"],
  #    ["/", "+", "*"], ["+", "*", "/"], ["+", "/", "*"]] 
anums, aops = nums.permutation(nums.size).to_a.uniq, ops.permutation(ops.size).to_a.uniq  
anums
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["1", "2", "4", "3"], ["1", "3", "2", "4"],
  #    ["1", "3", "4", "2"], ["1", "4", "2", "3"], ["1", "4", "3", "2"],
  #    ["2", "1", "3", "4"], ["2", "1", "4", "3"], ["2", "3", "1", "4"],
  #    ["2", "3", "4", "1"], ["2", "4", "1", "3"], ["2", "4", "3", "1"],
  #    ["3", "1", "2", "4"], ["3", "1", "4", "2"], ["3", "2", "1", "4"],
  #    ["3", "2", "4", "1"], ["3", "4", "1", "2"], ["3", "4", "2", "1"],
  #    ["4", "1", "2", "3"], ["4", "1", "3", "2"], ["4", "2", "1", "3"],
  #    ["4", "2", "3", "1"], ["4", "3", "1", "2"], ["4", "3", "2", "1"]] 
aops
  #=> [["*", "/", "+"], ["*", "+", "/"], ["/", "*", "+"],
  #    ["/", "+", "*"], ["+", "*", "/"], ["+", "/", "*"]]

a = anums.product(aops).map { |an,ao|
  ([an.first] + ao.zip(an[1..-1]).map(&:join)).join }
  #=> ["1*2/3+4", "1*2+3/4", "1/2*3+4",..., "4/3+2*1", "4+3*2/1", "4+3/2*1"] 
a.size
  #=> 144
```

Comment: This is what I thought the OP was asking for, too.  As per usual, you've made a thing of beauty.

Comment: Cary thanks for writing all this. The order of operations thing is part of a 24 solver problem that I'm working on for my portfolio, but the real killer is trying to parse out all the duplications. Your method spits out a lot of variations on the expression, but it doesn't parse out associative or commutative properties duplications. Eg, (1 + 2) + (3 * 4) == 1 + (2 + (3 * 4)). It would be a magnificent solution if you can incorporate that with your existing code. Again, thanks for your efforts. Sorry I am a quick shooter.

Comment: Ka, I'll see if I can incorporate parens this evening, but that does add quite a bit of complexity. Do you want that for the case where only operands are permuted or both numbers and operands are permuted?

Comment: No need to further dive into it. The problem is vastly complex. There's only one solver that I've found for the game 24 (http://www.4nums.com/solutions/), while all other ones have duplication like the example I gave. I'm happy with the solution I have on github. Feel free to make a 24 solver yourself if you're up to a challenge.  4num's page have a theory section where he explains how he parsed out all of duplicates, but it's too advanced for me atm.

Comment: Ka, I'm glad you found this helpful.